# In QGIS is there a way to make one polygon out of several

Tags: qgis, polygon

I'm trying to use QGIS to get a more simplified vector country data. For example Canada has several bits to the north all as separate polygons where as I'd be happy to just take a rough outline of the whole of it as one polygon.

I looked at using a convex hull, but that's a little too rough

Comment: Do they have a common attribute you can UNION on?

Comment: Concave hull is less rough.

Comment: @DPSSpatial well they are all from one feature, so I guess yes. Will take a look

Comment: Concave hull looks good - wish it had a mechanism to replace the feature (and take it's attributes), but I can do that manually

Comment: @user30184 if you put that comment as an answer I'll happily mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this guide](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/merging-polygons-in-qgis.html) to merge polygons using the toggle edit and then merge selected buttons.

Make sure the "Advanced Digitizing" toolbar is on
 - Right-click on any toolbar and you will see a list of available toolbars or use the menus and goto View > Toolbars

These are the basic steps:
 - Right-click the layer and choose "Toggle Editing"
 - Select items to merge
 - Click on the "Merge selected features" button which is the 3rd from last and looks like two polygons being sewn together with stitches

Comment: Thanks - but I couldn't find the buttons it wanted (merge polygons specifically).

Comment: Make sure the "Advanced Digitizing" toolbar is on
 - Right-click on any toolbar and you will see a list of available toolbars


These are the basic steps:

 - Right-click the layer and choose "Toggle Editing"
 - Select items to merge
 - Click on the "Merge selected features" button which is the 3rd from last and looks like two polygons being sewn together with stitches